# How does Stack overflow make their questions visible to search engines

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler

How are search engines able to crawl questions posted in stackoverflow or quora or any other forums and show them in the [search](http://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1DCTT_enIN450IN450&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cassandra%20cql%20php) results. Hope that link works

This might be similar to Facebook's [user profile visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957853/how-do-search-engines-see-dynamic-profiles) in search engines.

Do these sites keep updating their sitemap periodically?

Use Case: Trying to build a local events gathering website. Where events posted by users dynamically should be visible to search engines to crawl and appear in search results.

Some good & valid reference to understand the concept of sitemaps for this kind of usecases will really help.

Comment: The questions and answers are open to search engines to crawl. No need for a sitemap.

Comment: @Oded open to search engines means? If I visit stackoverflow.com I'll be able to see the site's home page. How does crawler know the url of the question for ex. the question I have asked now exists?

Comment: It crawls all links. The "Questions" tab is a link. The crawler follows that, then the "Newest" tab (also a link) etc... The bigger engines have heuristics that tell them which pages change most often, hence need to be crawled more often.

Comment: @Oded I can understand your point but How does it work in the case of quora where there are no links to questions exit in the home page? Are they because of external links only?

Comment: I don't know quora. But they probably have some _hidden_ links, or a sitemap to pages that have links to questions.

Comment: @Oded exactly that is what my question is. If it is bcoz of sitemap,  Will they update their sitemap periodically or some page that is being pointed by sitemap will contain links of all new questions which will get updated regularly?

Comment: Chances are that a page will get updated, though one could also create a dynamic sitemap. Not that it matters one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic SEO,

A combination of pretty-urls (/questions/32728/slug), well formed HTML with easy to parse headers and canonical information allows google and other search engines to crawl to as many corners of the site as possible simply by following links.

Google itself doesnt do anything in real time and neither does any search engine. Periodically google sends out their crawl bot to collect new or updated information about websites, and this is also where having your site connected to Google Webmaster tools also aids in visibility and availability, if the site owner connects webmaster tools (from google in this case) to their site, they not only open a flood gate of reporting capabilities, but also throws googlebot a higher priority of crawling. Inside of the webmaster tools is options and and settings that help googlebot understand where to find content and how to show the listings in results, and how to resolve the links in those listings.

By periodically, i mean ever couple days, to a week, sometimes upwards to a month. If you post a question now, it wont show up on google for about a week easily. google also raises priority of links shown based the content of the query itself vs the content of the page (title and body content making sense together are most important to google, metakeys and description are now tertiary and lower priority. For example you cant have a title that says "How to make Good Food" and have the content about PHP configurations). ALSO Google will prioritize results based on your search history if your logged in, also by search history of that IP address if your not logged in

Sitemaps also really help in sites that are hard to crawl from the front page. Notice how Faccebook requires you log in first. Googlebot doesnt have an account nor does it fill anything in to get anywhere. Sitemaps allow googlebot to figure out where to go on the site to start crawling. Otherwise facebook would only have 1 visible result.

To check to see how a website is doing in terms of searchable pages, put "site:" in front a web address into google, and you will see all available results google has about that site (and it will provide an estimated number of results if there's a great deal of them)

site:www.google.com 
and
site:google.com

the visibility and or requirement of the www. is also an important distinction as well.

Comment: Actually I remember a blog post by Jeff Atwood saying that their sitemap lists the URL to *every* question there is... not sure if this is still true.

Comment: Im pretty positive there is a read limit for the sitemap. Its pretty huge and more than enough for 80% of websites lol This said, I noticed one of my questions appeared immediately into google seconds after I posted it. Apparently the reason being here is that StackExchange is one of those lucky chosen sites by Google where google pings against a real-time RSS feed of some sort, allowing real-time results. Which is pretty nifty but much liek "Site Links" feature, Google has to opt you in manually on their own